# Infinity al inicializar una variable

Tags: java, netbeans

Buen día. Estoy tratando de realizar un código con funciones, me pide inicializar la variable est, y al inicializarla en 0, cuando corro el programa me aparece Infinity por la división en 0.
Esa variable se solicita al usuario entonces básicamente quiero que se guarde el valor que el usuario introduzca y se aplique el if.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       int nEstudiantes;
       double precioI=0, total;
       nEstudiantes=leerEst();
       precioI=calcularPrecio();
       total=precioI*nEstudiantes;
       System.out.println("Precio indiviual: $" + precioI);
       System.out.println("Total a pagar: $" + total);
    }
     public static double calcularPrecio(){
           double precio;
           int est;
           if (est>=100)
                 precio=65;
           else 
                if(est>=50 && est<=99 )
                    precio=70;
                else 
                    if( est>=30 && est<=49)
                        precio=95;
                    else
                    precio=4000.0/est;
                    return precio;
       }
       public static int leerEst(){
           int est;
         Scanner lector= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca el número de estudiantes: ");
        est=lector.nextInt();
        return est;
}
      
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que te parece si enviamos el parámetro en lugar de querer iniciar la variable `est`, porque al final nunca recibirá nada ya que no puede leer de otra función.

La acomodamos, de la siguiente manera.

```
public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    int nEstudiantes;
    double precioI = 0, total;
      nEstudiantes = leerEst ();
      precioI = calcularPrecio (nEstudiantes);
      total = precioI * nEstudiantes;
      System.out.println ("Precio indiviual: $" + precioI);
      System.out.println ("Total a pagar: $" + total);
  }
  public static double calcularPrecio (int est)
  {
    double precio;
    if (est >= 100)
      precio = 65;
    else if (est >= 50 && est <= 99)
      precio = 70;
    else if (est >= 30 && est <= 49)
      precio = 95;
    else
      precio = 4000.0 / est;
    return precio;
  }
  public static int leerEst ()
  {
    int est;
    Scanner lector = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("Introduzca el nC:mero de estudiantes: ");
    est = lector.nextInt ();
    return est;
  }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, se me pasó por completo.

Comment: Excelente, si te sirvió marca la respuesta como correcta para que le sirve de ayuda a alguien mas.